# Cognos Report Studio - Chart inside list

Tags: cognos

In Report Studio 11.1.7, how can I nest a chart inside/alongside a list such that there is a chart for each row which is filtered based on the data on a specific list column?

I found an old tutorial here: https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/big-data-&-business-intelligence/9781849680349/2/ch02lvl1sec18/creating-nested-report-defining-master-detail-relationship

But when I try it I get an error message at step 3. When I try to drag a new visualization next to the list I get "An object of this type cannot be inserted into a list".

I've tried fumbling around with unlocking the report, repeater tables, etc. but even if I can get the charts to appear in the correct spot, the "master-detail relationship" option is never available.

Any ideas?

Comment: You might need to include more data items due to dependency in order for the chart to render.  First try the chart on it's own and let me know if that works

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a master-detail relationship between the list and the chart.
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cognos-analytics/11.0.0?topic=wdq-create-master-detail-relationship

Not all visualization types support the master detail attribute, so you may have to play around with the type of object.  If you are still stuck let me know and I'll try and post an example spec.

Answer (score 0):

Some charts are a little easier to work with.  You can change the types of visualizations and charts to experiment.
Change the drop down to charts and start from there

Important step, when dragging the visualization onto the canvas, on the top (probably the right)  might be a drop down that opens up more options for you to explore

[image]

Also, if that does not work you can import more visualizations

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cognos-analytics/11.1.0?topic=visualizations-importing-into-library

Or create your own and upload them

Here is an example,

[image]